# ActiveMQ CPP Library

Tags: jms, messaging, activemq-classic

I have a Java application and a C++ application. I want to use Apache ActiveMQ for the communication between these applications. I know how to setup ActiveMQ, Run it etc.. I want to know what I should do to get the C++ client library. I tried downloading the code and running Make. It produced some libraries But I am not sure if its just the client library or the Whole ActiveMQ Server. Please provide some clarity or reference Links. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try doing some reading, there's plenty of information on the [website](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/) including a [getting started guide](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/cms-api-overview.html).  There's also several examples in the aptly named 'examples' directory in the source bundle.